# Is the comm command broken on Mac?

Tags: macos, unix, diff, bsd, comm

Suppose there are `file1`:

```
1
2
3
5
```

And `file2`:

```
2
3
4
```

When comparing them with `comm file1 file2` on FreeBSD or Linux, I got the following result:

```
1
                2
                3
        4
5
```

But when I tried the same command on Mac OSX 10.9, the result surprised me:

```
1
        2
        3
    4
```

Is the comm command broken on Mac? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works correctly on my Mavericks based iMac:

```
iMac:~/tmp: cat file1
1
2
3
5
iMac:~/tmp: cat file2
2
3
4
iMac:~/tmp: comm file[12]
1
    2
    3
    4
5
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I forgot to save `file1` so it did not contain `5`. Sorry for asking the dumb question.